# Does the wind direction have any effect on anything while sailing?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

In the previous game, the wind direction played a huge role in how fast you sailed (as expected).  If you sailed against the wind, you'd sail slower than if you had sailed with the wind.

In this game however, it doesn't seem to be the case.  You can sail at what seems to be the same speed if you sailed against the wind.  You even see the wind direction arrow turn red when going against it but still... no slowdowns.

I'm guessing it would have an influence on the direction rogue waves go during storms, but this also isn't the case.  It seems like the wind direction does absolutely nothing.

**Does the wind direction have any effect on anything while sailing?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it has a huge impact on how fast you sail. Sailing with the wind behind you (in the direction the arrow is pointing) is much quicker. Try it with just half-sail, sailing into the win half-sail you practically stop.

When sailing in storms travel speed is disabled forcing you to sail at either full or half sail. This is where the wind direction will come into play the most. Sailing in a storm will whip up the wind and waves meaning that sailing into the wind you will be heading front on into huge waves which, without the wind in your sails, will push your ship around quite a bit.

Different wind strengths will also affect your ship differently depending on which direction you are sailing relative to the wind direction. A huge gust hitting you front-on will practically stop your ship, whereas a big gust hitting from the side will tip the ship significantly to it's side.

Comment: So it only really has effect when going at slower speeds? I'm almost always traveling at travel speed (fastest) so I guess that's why I don't see the difference. I'd only slow down for battles or docking (and there's enough going on during battles it doesn't matter much how fast you're going).

Comment: It mostly comes into play when sailing in a storm, as you cannot use travel speed in a storm. Plus when you get freak gusts of wind, the amount of sail you have up and wind direction will have a huge impact on how far and which direction your ship is thrown.

Comment: Yeah, I just got my first taste of the wind. I didn't realize there were different levels of wind strength. I guess I just needed to get further in the game. When I initially asked, I was still in sequence 3 but revealed all the accessible parts of the map.